# Is it possible to add chart legend as a seperate custom component in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to add legend as a seperate component in flex charts. Actually my intention is ,
when user select item from legend .. corresponding chart item should be highlighted .
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You just need to add an event listener to the legend and highlight the corresponding chart item on the event handler.

```
// Assign an id to each legend item
<mx:LegendItem id="yourLegendItem" label="Your Label">

// Add a mouse click event listener to it
yourLegendItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, highlightYourChartItem);

// Handle the mouse clicks
function highlightYourChartItem(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  // Code to highlight the item. You can add a glow, change the color, etc
}
```

Here's a tutorial on how to create a separate legend control:
[Creating a custom Legend control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_12.html)